# SendGrid Node.js integration syntax issues

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, sendgrid

I'm trying to use SendGrid to send email notifications upon creation of a new order. So far it sends the email upon order creation but can't receive any of the data inside of the ${order.products.map...}. I'm using vs code and the bracket highlighting is off beginning in that area, it seems like I'm missing a closing bracket but I can't see it. Am I just creating this function incorrectly and vs code is telling me by showing wrong highlighting?

After looking at this code for too long I'm not sure what is wrong with it and I just need another pair of eyes to help me.

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('CREATE ORDER: ', req.body)
    req.body.order.user = req.profile
    const order = new Order(req.body.order)
    order.save((error, data) => {

    const emailData = {
      to: ['Payments@.com', '@.com'], // admin
            from: 'Payments@.com',
            subject: `A new order is received`,
            html: `
            <h1>Hey employee, get this stuff taken care of.</h1>
            <h2>Customer name: ${order.user.first_name} ${order.user.last_name}</h2>
            <h2>Customer address: ${order.delivery_address}</h2>
            
            <h2>User's email: ${order.user.email}</h2>
            <h2>Total products: ${order.products.length}</h2>
            <h2>Products: ${order.products}</h2>
            
            <h2>Order status: ${order.status}</h2>
            <h2>Product details:</h2>
            <hr />
            ${order.products
                .map(p => {
                    return `<div>
                        <h3>Product Name: ${p.name}</h3>
                        <h3>Product Price: ${p.price}</h3>
                        <h3>Product Quantity: ${p.quantity}</h3>
                        <h3>Product Seller: ${p.shop}</h3>
                </div>`;
                })
                .join('--------------------')}
            <h2>Total order cost: ${order.amount}<h2>
            <p>Login to your dashboard</a> to see the order in detail.</p>
        `
    }

    sgMail
            .send(emailData)
            .then(sent => console.log('SENT >>>', sent))
            .catch(err => console.log('ERR >>>', err));

    // email to buyer
    const emailData2 = {
      to: [order.user.email, 'Payments@.com'],
      from: 'Payments@.com',
      subject: `You order is in process`,
      html: `
      <h1>Hey ${order.user.first_name}, Thank you for shopping with us.</h1>
      <h2>Total products: ${order.products.length}</h2>
      
      <h2>Order status: ${order.status}</h2>
      <h2>Product details:</h2>
      <hr />
      ${order.products
          .map(p => {
              return `<div>
                  <h3>Product Name: ${p.name}</h3>
                  <h3>Product Price: ${p.price}</h3>
                  <h3>Product Quantity: ${p.quantity}</h3>
          </div>`;
          })
          .join('--------------------')}
      <h2>Total order cost: ${order.amount}<h2>
      <p>Thank your for shopping with us.</p>
  `
  }
  
  sgMail
            .send(emailData2)
            .then(sent => console.log('SENT 2 >>>', sent))
            .catch(err => console.log('ERR 2 >>>', err));

    res.status(200).json(data)
  })
  } catch (err){
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your problem or just something from sanitizing the code for public consumption, but you have a mismatched <a> tag here:  `<p>Login to your dashboard</a> to see the order in detail.</p>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, just removed the tag. Unfortunately that's not the easy fix I was hoping for

Comment: I'm assuming the email has `Total products: ` as something greater than zero?

Comment: I believe so but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. The email is only sent if something is created/ordered so by design it is always greater than 0

Comment: I'm just asking if the content of the email with the missing content says Total products: (a number above zero). An empty array would produce a missing section because there would be nothing to `map` or `join`